# Error when trying to set up Firebase Authentication for multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a Firebase Auth method for users to create an account. However I have multiple view controllers that required me to save the users information before I could process the Firebase Auth 'createUser' function. So I created a dictionary for that. I am also using Swift.

This is what I meant when I said I have more than one create an account view controller.

[image]

I then added created a dictionary in the App Delegate to save the users information before the Firebase 'createUser' method is activated.

```
 // Instance of AppDelegate
static let shared: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
// Dictionary for user information
var userInformation: Dictionary<String, Any> = [:]
```

Here is the code for the "enter your email address" view controller.

```
 // After Email is entered, next button is tapped to take user to second step of sign up process
@IBAction func nextButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    AppDelegate.shared.userInformation ["createEmail"] = emailTextField.text
```

And last for the "Name and Password" View controller. This is where I would like the email that was saved from the last view controller to come into place as well. I tried calling all of the saved information I stored in the dictionary so I can implenment the Firebase Auth.auth().createUser method.

```
IBAction func nextButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    AppDelegate.shared.userInformation["name"] = nameTextField.text
    AppDelegate.shared.userInformation["password"] = createPassWordTextField.text

    let createEmail = AppDelegate.shared.userInformation["createEmail."]
    let name = AppDelegate.shared.userInformation["name"]
    let password = AppDelegate.shared.userInformation["password"]

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: createEmail, password: password ) { (user, error) in
        if error == nil && user != nil {
            print("User Created!")
            // If user is created go to Welcome Page
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToWelcomeVC", sender: self)
        } else {
            print("error creating User")
```

After I would like the user's account to be created. Then they will be taken to the welcome page, then the home page. However I seem to be getting this error. Did I happen to do the dictionary incorrect? For my login view controller it was very simple. as you can see below.

```
 //Login Button

@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
  // Signing in User with Email and Password using Firebase
    if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text {

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
            // check if user isnt nil
            if user != nil {
                print("Login Successful")
                // user is found, go to home screen
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHomeVC", sender: self)
            } else {
                print("loginError")
```

I tried doing the same thing with the sign up view controllers by letting email, password, and name = UITextField.text. Can someone please assist me on what I did wrong here?

**Edit* Here is the error I am receiving.** 
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: add code instead of screenshots

Comment: Noted, my apologies mate. I thought screenshots would be the best way for everyone to visually see what I am trying to explain and what I see. Would you like me to remove all of the photos and add code instead?

Comment: keep mockup screenshot as it is and remove code screenshots and add code

Comment: Thanks mate. I have updated my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but 
`let createEmail = AppDelegate.shared.userInformation["createEmail."]` as you see it here your key is different from the first one, where you save info as `["createEmail"]` without the dot in the end.

Comment: Thank you for responding to me mate. I fixed that typo however I am still getting the same error. I will update the question showing the error. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Can you also show the error you're getting and  add a breakpoint when you make the request so we can see your variables values.

Comment: @Clint try 'Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: createEmail as! String, password: password )'

Comment: that worked!! Thank you. It also wanted me to change the password to ( password: password as! String) as well.

Comment: Ok, so approve the answer also ;)